# Is it possible to set an SPN with a path?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, kerberos

I'd like to know, if it is possible to set an SPN with non root url as something like that:

```
setspn -U -A http/www.example.com/someApp/path/ someServiceUser
```

So that different applications running in different IIS-Application Pools can have different SPNs

I tried the command, but it tells me that the name reference is invalid (which i can understand, since / is a special char in SPNs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. As far as I know, Kerberos service principals are always in the form `service/hostname` (exactly two components), and the hostname always matches the one that the client wants to access (not the one the server claims to be). It's possible for `HTTP/*` SPNs to include the port, but never the HTTP path.

Comment: That's not what i wanted to hear, but it matches my experience.

Comment: Btw this here is core information for me: the hostname always matches the one that the client **wants to access** (not the one the server claims to be) - i was not aware of that.

Comment: @Grumbler85: A small addition to that: MIT Kerberos and Heimdal (the most common Kerberos implementations for Unix(-like) systems) often use the "reverse DNS" of the server's address as the principal's hostname. However, Windows itself does not seem to do this, which makes sense given that DNS is insecure.